# How can I save data in my custom field. (Extends from User) Django

Tags: python, django

I am using django authentication system. I have my User model

```
class User(models.Model):
first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
username = models.CharField(max_length = 50, unique = True)
password = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

def __str__(self):
    return "%s %s" %(self.first_name, self.last_name)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

and recently I discovered that you cannot add some extra fields when you're using the django auth (for example: contact field). Google say, you can extend it. So, I extend it by making a UserProfile:

```
class UserProfile(User):
contact = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.contact_info
```

The problem is, I don't know how to add/save the data (contact) to the UserProfile. And how to display it in my template. I tried some but if failed:

views.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':

        fname = request.POST['fname']
        lname = request.POST['lname']
        contact = request.POST['contact']
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = User.objects.create_user(username, email=None, password=password)
        user.first_name = fname
        user.last_name = lname
        user.contact = contact
        user.save()

        user.contact = contact
        user.save()

        return redirect('system.views.user_login')
```

Is there any other way to save it?

Comment: [Extending the user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you saw that you can't add extra fields to your User model. You are already defining your own model; there is absolutely nothing to stop you from adding whatever fields you like.

However, if you are doing that, you must inherit from AbstractBaseUser, and set the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting to point to your model. Also, it makes no sense at all for you to define your User model as abstract.

Answer (score 0):

To extend django auth user model, you can use AbstractUser.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.contact_info
```